# Disable Perl warnings for missing qw outer parentheses

Tags: perl

Since upgrading Debian recently I've had Perl whining about not having extra parentheses around the qw operator.

As a Systems Administrator this is unacceptable. It is breaking mod_perl applications left, right, and centre.

How can I run Perl with this warning disabled? Is there a flag I can run with the Perl interpreter? Note that editing source is not an option.

Comment: Since when deos `qw` needs parentheses ?

Comment: @Kwaio http://blogs.perl.org/users/rurban/2010/09/qw-in-list-context-deprecated.html

Comment: That makes more sense. http://blogs.perl.org/users/rurban/2010/09/qw-in-list-context-deprecated.html#comment-4350 makes more sense tho. If it warns, it IS bad code

Comment: Never used to warn. For the best part of a decade.

Comment: You know what would be helpful? Posting what version(s) of Perl didn't have the behavior, and what version(s) do.

Comment: That doesn't really clarify the version question I have.

Comment: @mfinni: The behaviour changed in Perl 5.14.0.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This changed in Perl 5.14 - see [perldelta](https://metacpan.org/module/RJBS/perl-5.18.1/pod/perl5140delta.pod#Use-of-qw-...-as-parentheses).

> **Use of qw(...) as parentheses**
>
> Historically the parser fooled itself into thinking that qw(...)
>   literals were always enclosed in parentheses, and as a result you
>   could sometimes omit parentheses around them:
>
> ```
> for $x qw(a b c) { ... }
> ```
>
> The parser no longer lies to itself in this way. Wrap the list literal
>   in parentheses like this:
>
> ```
> for $x (qw(a b c)) { ... }
> ```
>
> This is being deprecated because the parentheses in for $i (1,2,3) {
>   ... } are not part of expression syntax. They are part of the
>   statement syntax, with the for statement wanting literal parentheses.
>   The synthetic parentheses that a qw expression acquired were only
>   intended to be treated as part of expression syntax.

Looks like you can turn the warnings off with `no warnings 'qw'` but you'd be far better off fixing the code.

Comment: Many thanks - the `no warnings 'qw'` pragma looks like a step in the right direction; can this be specified on the command line?

Comment: It **should** be `-M-warnings=qw`. But I can't get it to work.

Comment: If you have `use warnings;` in your code then that will override the `-M-warnings=`

Answer (score 5):

As a system administrator I find bad code unacceptable.

The best answer, of course, is to fix the offending perl scripts.

If your business won't let you fix the offending perl scripts, then don't upgrade Debian.

You have risks either way.

Comment: I wouldn't try to run code on a platform that doesn't support it. One of the two has to give.